# ASP net core datetime roundtrip none JsonSerializationSettings

Tags: asp.net-core

When using dynamic/JObject the Json date will be automcatily converted to a localized date. Is it possible to turn that off by in appsettings?

```
curl http://localhost:64233/api/nets/test \ 
  -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -d '{ 
    "dateTime": "2017-06-14T09:20:22+0000" 
}'

[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task<dynamic> TestAsync([FromBody] dynamic request)
{
    String dateTime = request.dateTime; <--- dateTime "06/14/2017 11:20:22" 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change how `JSON` serialization handles times zones in your `Startup` class by configuring `AddJsonOptions` in `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    });
}
```